# How to detect the closest value below and above a given reference variable in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, date, dplyr, closest

Consider the following random MWE.

For every row, I am trying to determine which variable has the closest value below the constant *reference_day* and which variable has the closest value above the constant *reference_day*.

```
df1 <-
  structure(
    list(id = 1:5,
      gender = c("female", "male", "male", "male", "male"),
      reference_day = structure(c(18052, NA, 18052, 18052, 18052), class = "Date"),
      var1 = structure(c(16505, 17144, 18139, NA, 16639), class = "Date"),
      var2 = structure(c(NA, 18042, 16544, 16697, NA), class = "Date"),
      var3 = structure(c(17845, 18070, 17152, 16571, NA), class = "Date")),
  row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df1

  id gender reference_day       var1       var2       var3
1  1 female    2019-06-05 2015-03-11       <NA> 2018-11-10
2  2   male          <NA> 2016-12-09 2019-05-26 2019-06-23
3  3   male    2019-06-05 2019-08-31 2015-04-19 2016-12-17
4  4   male    2019-06-05       <NA> 2015-09-19 2015-05-16
5  5   male    2019-06-05 2015-07-23       <NA>       <NA>
```

The result I'm after is this:

```
  id gender reference_day       var1       var2       var3 closest_to_left closest_to_right
1  1 female    2019-06-05 2015-03-11       <NA> 2018-11-10            var3             <NA>
2  2   male          <NA> 2016-12-09 2019-05-26 2019-06-23            <NA>             <NA>
3  3   male    2019-06-05 2019-08-31 2015-04-19 2016-12-17            var3             var1
4  4   male    2019-06-05       <NA> 2015-09-19 2015-05-16            var2             <NA>
5  5   male    2019-06-05 2015-07-23       <NA>       <NA>            var1             <NA>
```

After much trial and error, I was actually able to find a solution to this with the case_when function of dplyr, but it took an insane amount of boilerplate code, which lead me to think that there just has to be a more clever solution.

I personally prefer to work with dplyr, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A custom function to do this -

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- df1 %>% select(starts_with('var')) %>% names

closest_to_right <- function(x, y) {
  tmp <- y - x
  if(any(tmp > 0, na.rm = TRUE)) 
     cols[tmp %in% min(tmp[tmp > 0], na.rm = TRUE)] else NA
}

closest_to_left <- function(x, y) {
  tmp <- y - x
  if(any(tmp < 0, na.rm = TRUE)) 
     cols[tmp %in% max(tmp[tmp < 0], na.rm = TRUE)] else NA
}

df1 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(closest_to_left = closest_to_left(reference_day, c_across(starts_with('var'))),
         closest_to_right = closest_to_right(reference_day, c_across(starts_with('var')))) %>%
  ungroup

#     id gender reference_day var1       var2       var3       closest_to_left closest_to_right
#  <int> <chr>  <date>        <date>     <date>     <date>     <chr>           <chr>           
#1     1 female 2019-06-05    2015-03-11 NA         2018-11-10 var3            NA              
#2     2 male   NA            2016-12-09 2019-05-26 2019-06-23 NA              NA              
#3     3 male   2019-06-05    2019-08-31 2015-04-19 2016-12-17 var3            var1            
#4     4 male   2019-06-05    NA         2015-09-19 2015-05-16 var2            NA              
#5     5 male   2019-06-05    2015-07-23 NA         NA         var1            NA
```

Comment: The code is concise and efficient and works perfectly. But may I ask a question: if I gather it right, the function returns the "winner's"  - i.e. the one that is the closest - name by extracting an element from the list `cols`. But how does the function get the the right index of that list in the statement `cols[tmp %in% max(tmp[tmp < 0], na.rm = TRUE)]`?

Comment: `tmp` is of same length as `cols`. `max(tmp[tmp < 0], na.rm = TRUE)` would always return one value and so `tmp %in% max(...)` would also have only one `TRUE` value (if there are no same dates in a row). The corresponding value is extracted from `cols`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. Let us say there's an extra row `df1 <- df1 %>% add_row(id = 6, gender = "female", reference_day = as.Date("2019-06-05"), var1 = NA, var2 = as.Date("2020-01-01"), var3 = as.Date("2020-01-01"))`. Now there are two same dates - a usual situation in the real world - and the custom function throws in the error _closest_to_right must be size 1, not 2._ Would you go `first(cols[tmp %in% min(tmp[tmp > 0], na.rm = TRUE)]) else NA`? (I tried it, and it seems to work.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R solution. Probably there are simpler ways.

```r
nms <- names(df1[-(1:3)])
res <- apply(df1[-(1:2)], 1, \(x){
  d <- difftime(x[1], x[-1])
  if(any(!is.na(d))){
    if(any(d > 0, na.rm = TRUE)) {
      i <- which((d > 0) & (d == min(d[d > 0], na.rm = TRUE)))
      closest_left <- nms[i]
    } else closest_left <- NA
    if(any(d < 0, na.rm = TRUE)){
      j <- which((d < 0) & (d == min(d[d < 0], na.rm = TRUE)))
      closest_right <- nms[j]
    } else closest_right <- NA
    c(closest_left = closest_left, closest_right = closest_right)
  } else c(closest_left = NA, closest_right = NA)
})

res <- cbind(df1, t(res))
res
#>   id gender reference_day       var1       var2       var3 closest_left closest_right
#> 1  1 female    2019-06-05 2015-03-11       <NA> 2018-11-10         var3          <NA>
#> 2  2   male          <NA> 2016-12-09 2019-05-26 2019-06-23         <NA>          <NA>
#> 3  3   male    2019-06-05 2019-08-31 2015-04-19 2016-12-17         var3          var1
#> 4  4   male    2019-06-05       <NA> 2015-09-19 2015-05-16         var2          <NA>
#> 5  5   male    2019-06-05 2015-07-23       <NA>       <NA>         var1          <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I tested the code, and I confirm it works flawlessly. A beginner may notice that base R is not as "human-readable" as chains of dplyr commands even in a task as simple as the one posted here. However, there's a ton of things to learn in this solution, for which I am grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a relatively simple tidyverse approach. First we define a function to pick the closest match before or after the reference_day within each group, then we apply that in each case to add the two new columns. I use the `side` parameter to define whether we want matches on the side with negative time differences (before) or positive (after).

```
closest <- function(df, side = -1) {
  df %>%
    pivot_longer(-c(id:reference_day)) %>%
    group_by(id, gender) %>%
    arrange(value) %>%
    mutate(dif = (value - reference_day) * side) %>%
    filter(dif > 0) %>%
    slice_min(dif) %>%
    select(name) %>%
    ungroup()
}

df1 %>%
  left_join(df1 %>% closest(-1) %>% rename("left" = "name")) %>%
  left_join(df1 %>% closest(1) %>% rename("right" = "name"))
```

Result

```
  id gender reference_day       var1       var2       var3 left right
1  1 female    2019-06-05 2015-03-11       <NA> 2018-11-10 var3  <NA>
2  2   male          <NA> 2016-12-09 2019-05-26 2019-06-23 <NA>  <NA>
3  3   male    2019-06-05 2019-08-31 2015-04-19 2016-12-17 var3  var1
4  4   male    2019-06-05       <NA> 2015-09-19 2015-05-16 var2  <NA>
5  5   male    2019-06-05 2015-07-23       <NA>       <NA> var1  <NA>
```

Comment: I really like this answer in that its logic is easy to follow for beginners. Rather than only running the function, I broke it apart and then ran it line by line. However, one question arose in my mind: what is the purpose of the line `arrange(value) %>%` ? Could it be redundant, after all?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `tidyverse` approach:

1. First we calculate the difference of each var to the reference
2. Bring in long format
3. remove `diff_` in varname
4. Create a helper column using only negative values
5. group and arrange
6. identify `closest` to left and right again with redefining the helper column: now with only positive values.
7. fill both closest columns to select each first row of the group with `slice`.

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("var"), ~ parse_number(as.character(. - reference_day)), .names = "diff_{.col}")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("diff")) %>% 
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, '\\w+\\_'),
         helper = ifelse(value > 0, NA_real_, value)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(desc(helper), .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(closest_to_left = ifelse(helper == max(helper, na.rm = TRUE), name, NA_character_),
         helper = ifelse(value < 0, NA_real_, value),
         closest_to_right = ifelse(helper == min(helper, na.rm = TRUE), name, NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(closest_to_left, .direction = "downup") %>% 
  fill(closest_to_right, .direction = "downup") %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  select(-c(name, value, helper))
```

```
     id gender reference_day var1       var2       var3       closest_to_left closest_to_right
  <int> <chr>  <date>        <date>     <date>     <date>     <chr>           <chr>           
1     1 female 2019-06-05    2015-03-11 NA         2018-11-10 var3            NA              
2     2 male   NA            2016-12-09 2019-05-26 2019-06-23 NA              NA              
3     3 male   2019-06-05    2019-08-31 2015-04-19 2016-12-17 var3            var1            
4     4 male   2019-06-05    NA         2015-09-19 2015-05-16 var2            NA              
5     5 male   2019-06-05    2015-07-23 NA         NA         var1            NA
```

Comment: Yet another good solution, and a score of things to learn from this code as well. This solution differed from some other dplyr/tidyverse solutions in that the data was processed at one go, without using custom functions. When I ran the code, a few "no non-missing arguments" [to min/max] were thrown, but this was an expected thing. I hadn't realized before that you can use a "change switch" (here: the variable "helper") in a middle of a single mutate function!